# Times they are changing (font differences Mac/LaTeX)

Tags: fonts

Our designer developed a cover using times and small caps. We tried to implement this in LaTeX but for  reasons we do not understand the words come out longer in LaTeX.

[image: Original Design]

[image: Our results in LaTeX]

Is there anything we can do about this?

Comment: Exactly which fonts are you using? There are lots of 'Times New Roman' fonts, so it's important to know which ones you are using. Did you use micro-typography in either case?

Comment: Hard to tell for me without a grid superimposed on the bottom picture, but the smallcaps letters seem to be slightly larger. If it's a one-off job, manually kern, maybe make the lowercase letters 0.5pt smaller, things like that.

Comment: you seem to point at a difference between a Mac system font and the LaTeX used font: perhaps you could use `xelatex` and `fontspec` to pick up the system font?

Comment: Take into account the difference between real small caps and fake small caps. http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex#smallcaps

Comment: Hm, the xelatex option may work, but we develop a class for an open access project and it is supposed to work on all machines. I guess we are not allowed to distribute the mac system fonts, are we? So we needed a free Times with true small caps.

Comment: TG Termes does contain true small caps, is freely redistributable and comes with pdf-latex-compatibility too. Its smallcaps are a bit less tightly spaced than your first example, but much better than the second.

Answer (score 6):

There are any number of reasons to get differences. As has been noted in the comments there are many "Times" fonts (some more alike than others). Especially for small caps, some use designed small caps fonts, some just fake it by scaling full caps, and if so scale by different amounts. Finally the units may be different (a TeX point isn't the same as a PostScript one). It would be much easier to tell which of these is relevant here given the PDF rather than a PNG image however for a one-off cover sheet you don't really need to know *why* as you can force things to be (more) the same.

Just measure each line in your target document and if you want `Phrase Structure` to be on one line and  15.2345cm wide then you can use

```
\resizebox{15.2345cm}{!}{Phrase Structure}
```

This needs `graphicx` package of course.

Comment: sorry, david; this is really bad.  i don't like to downvote, but i simply can't agree that this is the right way to go.

Comment: @barbarabeeton actually I don't understand your objection at all. The current font is using the caps and small caps in the ratio set up for _this_ version of Times, and if you scale it all in proportion that is no different from any other font size change. If you scale the small caps and not the full caps you are changing the relative sizes which is OK if you are a font designer, but hard  to get right otherwise, and you lose the inter-letter kerns.

Comment: the problem as posed was to match the designer's image.  i agree with you that the two versions of times have quite different design criteria.  but it's impossible, under those circumstances, to match what the designer produced.  i believe that retaining the proportions of the font used by the designer is more important than just matching the horizontal size.  this leaves as the only tex-only answer, to determine the original font and use it -- which appears to be impossible.  maybe a pdf graphic of the designer's image is an acceptable "way out".

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions and discussions! The problem is that we want to produce a bundle and give it to authors, so we cannot give fonts away. But maybe we live with a temporary imperfection for the authors and I do the final latex stuff and use the Mac fonts. This would be at least a working solution, not the perfect one though.

Answer (score 3):

david's answer sounds nice, but you don't want to reduce the size of the *real* caps, only the *small* ones.  so things are more complicated.

i suggest measuring the height of the two different small cap "H"es
(no problems with optical overrun, since it's got a nearly "flat" top and bottom")
and scaling to a percentage.  still needs the `graphicx` package.

```
D\scalebox{.93}{anish} \scalebox{.93}{in}\\
H\scalebox{.93}{ead}-D\scalebox{.93}{riven}\\
P\scalebox{.93}{hrase} S\scalebox{.93}{tructure}\\
G\scalebox{.93}{rammar}
```

*the .93 is only a wild guess!  please measure!*

actually, the scale factor applies to the horizontal measure, but i think it's
safe to assume that the proportions of the various letters aren't all that different
in the two renditions, and it's simpler to measure a vertical element.  the same
scaling factor will be applied both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Anyways, it would be an abuse of the font to use a different x- and y-scale, so one should choose which is more important for them...

Comment: Hmm doing that though you lose any Kerns between the letters `Da` looks suspiciously as if it has an inter-letter kern in the original. (Of course, you could put the spacing back in by hand, chosen to match the new relative sizes)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- i think putting the spacing back in will give a better result than smallifying the real caps.  either way, it's nasty.  best solution would be to determine what font was used for the original design, and using that.